# save individual model output from a list of model summary

Tags: r, file, save, output, regression

I have looped a list of variables in a regression model, and saved the outputs as a list, how can I output the models from the list into individual text files?

```
varlist <- list(var1, var2, var3)

mlist <- lapply(varlist, function(x) {
     lmer(substitute(y ~ x1*x2*i + (1|ID), 
     list(i = as.name(x))), data = df)
 })

mlist_summ <- lapply(mlist, summary)

# how can I save mlist_summ in files? How can I give them different file names? 
# I have tried the following:

for(i in mlist_summ){
   stargazer(i$coefficients, type = "text", out = ... )
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a better approach would be to use:

```
for(i in seq_along(mlist_summ)){
  stargazer(mlist_summ[[i]]$coefficients, type = "text", out = paste0("summary_", i, ".txt"))
}
```

This way you can control the filenames.

Full example with `lm` and `mtcars` data:

```
library(stargazer)
data(mtcars)

varlist <- list("cyl", "disp", "hp")

mlist <- lapply(varlist, function(x) {
  lm(substitute(mpg ~ i, 
                  list(i = as.name(x))), data = mtcars)
})

mlist_summ <- lapply(mlist, summary)

for(i in seq_along(mlist_summ)){
  stargazer(mlist_summ[[i]]$coefficients, type = "text", out = paste0("summary_", i, ".txt"))
}
```

Another approach would be to extract the coefficients first:

```
mlist_summ <- lapply(mlist, function(x){
  summary(x)$coefficients})
```

and provide that list to stargazer:

```
stargazer(mlist_summ, type = "text", out = "summary.txt")
```

This way all the models will be in one file.